# Is it possible to write a log to a single file from several locust slaves?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, load-testing, locust

I use locust on several machines (https://locust.io/). Each *--slave* and *--master* node with the *--logfile* option writes a log to its directory.
Is it possible to make them write a common log to a single file?
Since it is very inconvenient to collect and analyze logs from all machines every time.

Comment: I am not familiar with locust, but I do use `loguru` https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ on clusters to write logs from different workers to the same file using its `enqueue` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what it is that you're analyzing from the logs (so this might or might not be the answer you're looking for), but you can use Locust's `--csv` command line option (and possibly also `--csv-full-history`), to have the master node continuously write the aggregated request statistics and failures in CSV format to files.

Comment: I register all unsuccessful responses from the server, and it would be nice to see in one file which error the server returned, to which request and on which machine.

Comment: Then I'd recommend that you use some third party logging server or database to report and store that centrally. Or - if the only issue with your current solution is that you manually have to fetch all log files - write a script that downloads and merges all the log files.